# issue with iOS 6 autorotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a viewcontroller in which I wanted it to be presented only in portrait, so I did the following in iOS 6:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

however when I rotate the device, it still turns it to landscape. Any idea where else to check this? I put a break point and it hits `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, but it still rotates

Comment: is your controller inside UINavigationController?

Comment: In your Xcode target settings check if you have selected only portait in supported interface orientation.

Comment: i dont want my app to only support portrait, I have a few vc that i want to make such that it only supports portrait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a navigation controller? The way that iOS6 determines what can be autorotated has changed. It is correctly asking supportedInterfaceOrientations for your view controller but it is probably asking "shouldAutorotate" to another element in your navigation stack hierarchy and accepting that answer. If your navigationController/tabviewController returns yes to this question then it won't consult with your view controller.

Comment: no I don't have a navigation controller, this is just a view controller, basically just adding it as a subview

Comment: Ok then look in your "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" function in your app delegate and make sure your window is not just adding your viewControllers view as a subview but that you are setting the UIWindow's rootViewController to your viewController

Comment: Thank you, rooster117! I've been trying to solve this for a while now, but didn't see anyone else explaining the detail about the UIWindow.

Answer (score 2):

You should also provide the apps supported orientations in the app delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Make sure you add the root view controller properly (not adding it as a subview), but using the following:

```
[window setRootViewController:myVC];
```

Also if your view controller is inside a `UINavigationController`, you should use this category for the navigationcontroller:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (autorotate)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

In iOS 6, only the root view controller of the top most full screen controller is asked about rotation. This includes `UINavigationController`, this class does not ask it's view controllers, it responds directly. Apple now suggest subclassing `UINavigationController` to override `supportedInterfaceOrientations's` output.

Comment: I have a view controller that I only want to support portrait only, so not the whole app supports portrait

Comment: You should still provide this method in the delegate with all the orientations possible for your app. Make sure you add your view controller as the root, not it's view as a subview. Also please check the info.plist orientations of the project

Comment: hmm.. in my app delegate I dont have window setting my vc as root. i am setting all of this up using storyboard, i there a way to do so in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **project settings and info.plist** have **only** portrait orientation selected as they have a higher priority than the app delegate when checking for supported orientations